# SQL: Updating a table updates only 7 rows at a time

Tags: sql, database, sybase

While executing a SQL update,

```
update request set state_id = 2 where id in (
           select id from request where state_id = 0 and entity_id in 
           (<list of numbers>)
)
```

This updates only 7 rows at a time.

The inner select query,

```
 select id from request where state_id = 0 and entity_id in (<list of numbers>)
```

returns 2000+ records.

I am using Squirrel SQL client to run the query and checked if the limit rows is set to 3000.

What makes it more interesting is, if I wait for more time in between successive executing of the update query, more rows gets updated. 
I mean, When I waited for 10 secs, and executed the update, 45 rows got updated. 
but when ran rapidly, just 7 rows gets updated.

Can someone please help me point out what I might be doing wrong?

Executing the inner select - 
[image: Select:]

Executing the update - 
[image: Update:]

Comment: What is the count of `select COUNT(DISTINCT id) from request where state_id = 0 and entity_id in (<list of numbers>)` ?

Comment: id is a primary key. count is 2192. I tried using the select with distinct. Still just 7 rows got updated.

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM request where ID in ( select id from request where state_id = 0 and entity_id in (<list of numbers>) )` 
&

`select COUNT(DISTINCT id) from request where state_id = 0 and entity_id in (<list of numbers>)`
returns same result.

Comment: also, Sybase is a brand, not a database..what product are you using?  ASE? SQLAnywhere? IQ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest writing a proper update, since I see no reason to introduce a more complex query involving a subquery. Also just to be sure you didn't previously alter `@@ROWCOUNT`:

```
SET @@ROWCOUNT 0;

UPDATE dbo.request
  SET state_id = 2
  WHERE state_id = 0 
  AND entity_id IN (<list of numbers>);
```

Also check that you haven't artificially limited the row count in Management Studio. In Tools > Options:

[image]

(Well, that would have been relevant if you had tagged correctly. Check whatever client tool you use against Sybase and see if it has some similar option.)

Comment: Thanks Aaron, I verified that.. the rowcount is set to 3000 right now. Weird thing is, if i execute the update maintaining some time interval, the number of rows that gets updated changed! I am updating and selecting the same table, not sure if I am missing anything to take care of?

Comment: @ajc does not sound logical to me, sorry. Did you try my query? I'm not familiar with Sybase. I only landed on this question *because you tagged it wrong.*

Comment: @AaronBertrand ... yes I tried with setting rowcount. Added screen captures for more clarity. Its still behaving the same. Thanks for re tagging it, I'll make sure to tag a question accurately here on.